# 'unused argument' error when using `purrr::pwalk` to save ggplots from list column in nested dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I'm trying to save out ggplots from a list column in a nested dataframe with the nesting variable in the filename so that I know which plot corresponds to which data.

I'm using an approach which worked for me saving csv files from nested dataframes, but doesn't work with ggplot objects.

```
data("mtcars")
temp_dir <- tempfile()
dir.create(temp_dir)
library(tidyr) # for nest function

plot_fun <- function(x){
  p <- ggplot(data = x, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_point()
  return(p)
}

cyl_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  nest(data = -cyl) %>% 
  mutate(plots = map(.x = data, .f = plot_fun)
  )
head(cyl_mtcars)
```

Which produces

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
    cyl data               plots 
  <dbl> <list>             <list>
1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>  <gg>  
2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]> <gg>  
3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]> <gg>
```

But when I try to save the figures out

```
cyl_mtcars %>% 
  pwalk(
    function(cyl, plots) ggsave(filename = file.path(temp_dir, glue("{cyl}.png")), plot = plots)
    )
```

I get this error

````
Error in `pmap()` at purrr/R/pmap.R:148:2:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `.f()`:
! unused argument (data = .l[[2]][[i]])
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that using `pwalk` or `pmap` all columns are passed to the function. And as your function has only two arguments you get an *unused argument* error as you nested data has three columns. To fix that, you could add `...` to the function arguments:

```r
temp_dir <- tempfile()
dir.create(temp_dir)

library(tidyverse)

plot_fun <- function(x) {
  ggplot(data = x, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point()
}

cyl_mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  nest(data = -cyl) %>%
  mutate(plots = map(.x = data, .f = plot_fun))

cyl_mtcars %>% 
  pwalk(
    function(cyl, plots, ...) {
      ggsave(filename = file.path(temp_dir, glue::glue("{cyl}.png")), plot = plots)
    }
  )
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```